# Error occurred while starting the build in Openshift 3

Tags: jboss, openshift, openshift-3

[image]I have been trying to deploy a war file as an OpenShift project. The server used is  jboss-webserver30-tomcat8. I have followed the below steps -

1. Put ROOT.war file under 'deployments' directory in local system.
2. Upload the changes in github.
3. Create a new JAVA project in OpenShift 3 and provide the github repository details.

No automatic build or deployment starts. On manually clicking on Start Build button, the below error is displayed:

> An error occurred while starting the build. Reason: Error resolving
> ImageStreamTag jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift:1.2 in namespace
> openshift: unable to find latest tagged image

Please suggest how can I resolve the error.

Comment: This looks like a bug on our side. The template needs to be updated to the latest version. I'm putting a request in now.

Comment: Can you please confirm if this is a bug or the issue is caused due to the downtime. I am attaching the screenshot from Image Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with how the jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift imagestream is defined in the cluster. We are working to correct this, it is not currently importing the correct set of tags and as a result the 1.2 tag was stopped being a valid tag, when it should be.

However the short term solution is change your buildconfig to reference one of the tags that has a valid image reference associated (e.g. 1.3) instead of the 1.2 tag it is currently referencing.  Your build should then be able to run.

Comment: Can you please help me with an issue after build and deployment? On hitting the url, I am receiving blank page. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Sounds like maybe your application did not deploy successfully, I'd suggest you look at the pod logs (which will be the logs for the tomcat server) and see if there's anything obvious.  Also are you sure your application is registered at the root path?

Comment: I have posted a separate question related to this issue. Please have a look. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128327/blank-page-opening-after-running-a-project-in-openshift

Below errors are observed -

1. Build config instantiate failed (error instantiating Build from BuildConfig adore-india/adoreindia (0): Error resolving ImageStreamTag jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift:1.2 in namespace openshift: unable to find latest tagged image)

The context directory has been selected as / under source configuration.

Comment: The error resolving the imagestreamtag is resolved by my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

A (temporarily) unavailable builder image may be related to [this platform upgrade](https://status.starter.openshift.com/incidents/12gbxq4cd1v4) that correlates with the time of posting your question.

---

Generally, the best place to check for any incident reports or scheduled maintenance is the Status Page ([Starter](https://status.starter.openshift.com/) | [Pro](https://status.pro.openshift.com/) clusters; it's linked in the web console too, in the upper right corner of the interface).
If this does not seem to be related (e.g. you're not on the `starter-us-west-2` cluster where the platform upgrade is taking place) or persists after the maintenance is over, I would encourage you to check the [open issues](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=ON_DEV&bug_status=ON_QA&classification=Red%20Hat&known_name=Online%20v3&list_id=5138398&product=OpenShift%20Online&query_based_on=Online%20v3&query_format=advanced&version=3.x), and log a [new bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online&version=3.x), if it's not in the list.

Thank you.