# Blank page opening after running a project in openshift

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, github, jboss, openshift

I have deployed a web application in openshift. Although build and deployment was successful, I am getting a blank page on clicking the application :

http://adoreindia-adoreindia.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/

Below is the pom.xml.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.adore.india.actions</groupId>
  <artifactId>Adore_india_project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ognl</groupId>
      <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>Adore_india_project</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The application is running fine in local system. Please suggest how do I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing profiles tag and correcting the context root, artifact id as **your-context-root-name** has resolved the issue.

Application url -

[http://adoreindia-project-adore-india-project.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/your-context-root-name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/](http://adoreindia-project-adore-india-project.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/adore-india-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/)

Below is the modified pom.xml.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.adore.india.actions</groupId>
  <artifactId>adore-india-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ognl</groupId>
      <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>Adore_india_project</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles> -->
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the build log look for the name of the .war file:

[INFO] Building war: /tmp/src/target/yourcontextrootname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

"yourcontextrootname" is the context root of the app - you should see your context root name. ([How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse))

To be able to access my app in OpenShift3 Starter, i had to append the name of my .war file after the URL like this

...adoreindia-adoreindia.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/yourcontextrootname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Build log shows the name of war file as - 

[INFO] Building war: /tmp/src/webapps/ROOT.war

I have modified the context root of the web application to ROOT. That does not work and still shows blank page. I have observed 2 warnings under events as - 

1. Unable to mount volumes for pod "adoreindia-3-deploy_adore-india(3805e0d4-99cf-11e7-a546-06579ed29230)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "adore-india"/"adoreindia-3-deploy". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[deployer-token-ngq25]
2. Error syncing pod

Comment: I can't say anything about those warnings. Never had any like that. This is how my webapp works:
The build is triggered by a webhook in the git repository at each push.
In my pom.xml i don't have the <profiles> section. There is probably the difference, that is why your .war file is named ROOT. I think the context root should be what it was before, the link i provided was there only for clarification, where the name of context root can be found.
Other than these informations i can only say, i had to re-create the webapp in OpenShift3 many times from scratch, before it ran correctly.